# ModalViewController Without Dimming / Disabling current viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller

I am displaying aNavController as a modalViewController in a specific frame CGRectMake(40,50, 400, 500). Which is working fine. Now I have a button in self (viewcontroller on which modalViewController is presented), on pressing that button I need to display some message on aNavController. But problem is when I am presenting a modalViewController. Whole screen area got dimmed/disabled. So, not able to touch/click that button in self.

Here is my code to present a view controller. I thought, I am missing something here. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

```
aNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
anavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];
aNavController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(40,50, 400, 500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to do workaround the things which work same way as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

I added the aNavController as a subview to the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] and which solves my all the problems.

Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

presentModalViewController create a modal dialog. When modal view controller is up, users can't do any thing on parent view until the the modal view is dismissed.

Comment: Yes you are right, user are not able do any thing on parent view until the model view is dismissed. I know that thing, Here I want a any workaround at it. anyways, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're instantiating a `UIAlertView` at the same time as the `presentModalViewController` call your modal view in `UIAlertView`'s delegate method `clickedButtonAtIndex`.

Like so:

```
- (IBAction)clickedMyButton:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                 initWithTitle: @"Title"
                 message: @"Message"
                 delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Close Button"
                 otherButtonTitles:@"Modal Button", @"Some Other Button", nil];
    [alertView show];
}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"User Selected Cancel");
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Modal Button Clicked");
        aNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        anavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];
        aNavController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(40,50, 400, 500);
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Some Other Button Clicked");
    }
}
```

Or, if you wish for your `UIAlertView` to show on top of your navigation controller, ignore the above and simply wait to call your alert until the navigation controllers `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

In addition, I recommend you change your frame to stay within the bounds of the screen unless absolutely necessary. ex: `CGRectMake(40, 50, 320, 480);`